# Simple C++ String Reversal

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string, but the following does NOT work. Here's my I/O:

```
Enter text to be reversed: 
>> Alex
Reversed, it is: llex
```

Here's my code:

```
string Reversal(string name) {

    for(double i = name.length() - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j = 0;
        name[j] = name[i];
        j++;
    }
    return name;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string name;
    cout << "Enter text to be reversed: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Reversed, it is: " << Reversal(name) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: It works fine when I use the reverse function built into the library:

```
reverse(name.begin(),name.end())
```

I just want to know why my function won't work. I'm trying to reverse the string without using any additional strings.

Comment: Why are you using double in the for loop

Comment: @EdHeal It said there was data loss when using int i to give it the value of name.length(). I just used double to shut up the warning (OCD about those yellow warnings haha).

Comment: Add `cout << name << endl;` inside the loop, and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: @molbdnilo It appears that only the first index of the name[j] is being swapped using the end of name. However, I'm increasing j by one every time that for loop is run. Why is it not doing anything?

Comment: @Alok: Get out a pencil and paper and write down the contents of `name` for every step of your loop. You should immediately see why your `for` loop doesn't work.

Comment: This interview will be... interesting.

Comment: Yeah after a careful look, I realize how blatant my mistake was, haha. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing j at the end of your loop, but you are setting its' value to 0 at the beginning anyway, so you are always looking only at the first character.

The other problem with your code is that, you are overwriting the other half of your array when iterating from the beginning. One of solutions to this is to swap the characters as you go and end at the middle.

Exapmle:

```
int j = 0;
int i = name.length() - 1;
while(i > j){
    char temp = name[j];
    name[j] = name[i];
    name[i] = temp;
    j++;
    i--;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I realize how blatant my mistake was. Thanks for your help!